# What are the types of singularities of $\frac{z^{1/3}-1}{z-1}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity, branch-cuts

The function $f(z) = \frac{z^{1/3} - 1 }{z-1}$ has a branch point at $z = 0$.  How do I tell what kind of singularities $f$ has at $z=1$ depending on the branch taken?

The explanation I have been given is that letting $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $0 \leq \theta<2\pi$, $z=1$ is a removable singularity; letting $z = re^{i\theta}$ for $2\pi \leq θ < 4\pi$, $z = 1$ is a simple pole; letting $z=re^{i\theta}$ for $4\pi\leq\theta<6\pi$, $z=1$ is a simple pole.

Why is the singularity in the last two cases a simple pole instead of a removable singularity?

Comment: I don't see why you would get a simple pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To investigate the singularity at $z=1$, let's change variables $w=z-1$ and investigate the singularity at $w=0$.

$$
\frac{z^{1/3}-1}{z-1} = \frac{(1+w)^{1/3}-1}{w}
$$
First case...
Using the branch of the cube root with $1^{1/3}=1$, we get as $w \to 0$:
\begin{align*}
(1+w)^{1/3} &= 1 + \frac{1}{3}w + o(w^2)\\
(1+w)^{1/3} - 1 &= \frac{1}{3}w + o(w^2)\\
\frac{(1+w)^{1/3}-1}{w} &= \frac{1}{3} + o(w)
\end{align*}
Thus, the singularity at $w=0$ is removable.

.....

Here is the graph of $\displaystyle \frac{z^{1/3}-1}{z-1}$ from $z=0$ to $2$ ... See the value $\frac13$ at $z=1$.

[image: graph]

...

Second case: Using the branch with $1^{1/3}= \omega = \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we get
\begin{align*}
(1+w)^{1/3} &= \omega\left(1+\frac{1}{3}w+o(w^2)\right)
=\omega + \frac{\omega}{3}\;w + o(w^2)
\\
(1+w)^{1/3}-1 &=
(\omega-1) + \frac{\omega}{3}\;w + o(w^2)
\\
\frac{(1+w)^{1/3}-1}{w} &=\frac{\omega-1}{w} + \frac{\omega}{3} + o(w)
\\ &=  \frac{-3+i\sqrt{3}}{2}\;\frac{1}{w} + \frac{-1+i\sqrt{3}}{6} + o(w)
\end{align*}

Third case: Using the branch with $1^{1/3}=\frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we get
$$
\frac{(1+w)^{1/3}-1}{w} = \frac{-3-i\sqrt{3}}{2}\;\frac{1}{w} + \frac{-1-i\sqrt{3}}{6} + o(w)
$$

In these two cases we have poles at $z=1$ with residues that can be read here.